# How to use a reusable library in kotlin, with android and javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin

Well, I'm trying to create a library to be used by **Android** application and **web (JavaScript)**. The **library will be written in Kotlin**, and I saw Kotlin is 100% operable with JS and Java, so I think it can be posible but I didn't find de correct way or the best practice for this case. Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to compile your library to both targets. Also, you cannot use classes that are specific to JS or Java. Classes written in Java will not work on JS, and vice versa.

Comment: No, sorry, maybe I didn't explain correctly, the library will be written in kotlin, and kotlin can work with JS and Java, do you understand me?

Comment: But what happens if the library use the kotlin pluguin?

Comment: @IsaacAlvarezGil Yes, I understand you. You just need to be careful not to use any classes from, for example, Java in your implementation. Or the `dynamic` keyword that only works for Javascript. It will be caught when you try to compile to both targets though.

Comment: @marstran I don't understand one thing, if Java class can be fully converted to Kotlin, and Kotlin can compile to JavaScript, why can't you use Java class from Kotlin and then compile to JavaScript?

Comment: @lelloman If you convert the Java class source code to Kotlin, it is no longer Java. Doing that will make it work for KotlinJS. However, you can not use for example `java.util.ArrayList` when you compile to a JS target. You don't have access to the Java standard library when you compile to JS.

Comment: @marstran in this last case, with the kotlin pluguin you don't import arraylist from java, the import comes from kotlin library....

Comment: @MerlíEscarpenterPérez ArrayList was just an example... If you use it directly (not through Kotlin's `listOf` function), the Kotlin plugin can't fix it for you.

Comment: @marstran Excuse me, what will not Kotlin do for us?

Comment: My only point is that you can only use things from the Kotlin stdlib (which is not specific to Java or JS) if you want to compile to both targets... For example, do not use the `dynamic` keyword or explicitly write `import java.util.ArrayList`.